# How do I test for equality in parameters for two time series data sets described by the same NLS model?

Tags: r, nls

I am currently in the midst of fitting curves to sales volumes of 2 successive product generations over an observation period. I am looking at two different markets. Through some research, I have identified a nonlinear model that fit the data well in both markets. To estimate the parameters of the model, I am using R and the package, nls2.

I have obtained regression output for the markets two individually. 
Now, I would like to test whether the estimated parameters are different from each other on the two markets. That is, I would like to test each model parameter from one market against the corresponding parameter estimate from the other market.

Is there any function in R or in the nls2 package, that will allow me to do that? Or is there a smarter method?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the parameters using MANOVA.